# sql server invalid precision on exists check query

Tags: sql-server, perl, sql-server-2008, dbi

Using sql server 2008 I am getting and invalid precision value error in the following perl script:

```
use DBI;
$idx = '12345';
$query = 'if exists (select * from tbl where idx = ?) select top 10 * from tbl';
my $h = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "Couldn't prepare query: " . $dbh->errstr;
$h->execute($idx) or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $h->errstr;
```

Note however that if I try this instead

```
use DBI;
$query = 'if exists (select * from tbl where idx = \'12345\') select top 10 * from tbl';
my $h = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "Couldn't prepare query: " . $dbh->errstr;
$h->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $h->errstr;
```

then it works.  I am really confused at how the ? in the query could possibly be causing an invalid precision error.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: What is the data type of idx in tbl?

Comment: idx is a varchar.  The exact text of the error is 

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Invalid precision value (SQL-HY104) at filename.pl ...

Comment: Complete guess but what if you try `if exists (select * from tbl where idx = '?') select top 10 * from tbl`

Comment: i tried that, it ended up passing the ? character directly into sql without substituting it.

Comment: Another complete guess...can you explicitly force the datatype: `if exists (select * from tbl where idx = cast(? as varchar(30))) select top 10 * from tbl` Adjust `varchar(30)` as appropriate to match the definition of idx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=491253), please try the following:

> You need to import the SQL type constants from DBI 
>   and specify that SQL_LONGVARCHAR as the type of the data to be added to the memo field.

To do that you do:

$dbh->bind_param(1, $idx, SQL_LONGVARCHAR);

Comment: Please note that I'm 100% certain it will help if your `idx` column  is longer than 255 characters. If it isn't, it might work but I'm less certain since 255 char limit is what is usually causing such an error in the first place.

Comment: It turns out that it was a varchar(9), but if I used SQL_VARCHAR then this does in fact work.  Any idea why it works though?  

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chuck - the only inteligent idea I have at the moment is having an "int" like value... does the original code barf if the value is a non-number-looking string?

Comment: All the indices have both letters and numbers.  It still barfs either way.  

It has something to do with the exists subquery since if I just insert or select , this is fine, and if I put a literal term in the exists and combine this with an insert or select this is fine.  It only breaks when attempting to use a placeholder in the exists subquery

Comment: Heh... no idea but I'm as happy as a clam that I always avoid bound parameters on principle. Too much headache :)

Answer (score 1):

Binding with a specific type overrides what DBD::ODBC decides. DBD::ODBC will bind the parameter based on what comes back from SQLDescribeParam. Sometimes SQL Server's SQLDescribeParam fails, especially in cases where you are using functions or subselects. The SQL Server ODBC driver takes your SQL and rearranges it to attempt to end up with something like "select idx from tbl" then it looks at the columns to answer SQLDescribeParam calls. I'm betting the SQL Server ODBC driver fails to rearrange your SQL in this case and either SQLDescribeParam failed or returned the wrong information. If you enable tracing in DBD::ODBC we could probably see this happening.